# plotting an iv-curve with python

Tags: python, curve

So I am trying to plot an IV-curve using python, but all I'm getting is a straight, linear line. This may seem like a trivial code, but I just started self teaching myself literally a week a go, so bear with me as I am still learning :)

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xdata = [20,27] # voltage data
ydata = [0.4,0.9] # current data
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.title(r'IV-curve')
plt.xlabel('Voltage(V)')
plt.ylabel('Current(I)')
plt.show()
```

A picture of it is shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGryK.jpg

Comment: You have only two points. What kind of graph do you expect?

Comment: @AndreyLukyanenko just a simple, 2D IV curve. Any changes I need to make?

Comment: @AndreyLukyanenko an exponential curve I might add.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can try something like below (change equation to set 'y' based on your requirements):
[image]